# How do I call C from Go using the "foreign function interface"

Tags: c, go, ffi

How do I use Go's "foreign function interface" to call out to a C function?

This interface is mentioned on the [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Do_Go_programs_link_with_Cpp_programs), but I cannot see it mentioned elsewhere in the docs.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go

Answer (score 18):

Check out [this file](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/misc/cgo/gmp/gmp.go) from the Go repository. It shows how to wrap a C library in Go and has quite a few comments that explain the process.

Comment: That's a very well documented file! I had begun writing an answer but decided to check that file out and then deleted my unfinished answer after reading.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [article](http://golang.org/doc/articles/c_go_cgo.html) that demonstrates the following with [Cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> To lead with an example, here's a Go package that provides two
>   functions - `Random` and `Seed` - that wrap C's `rand` and `srand` functions.