# Can I use c++ in cgo?

Tags: c++, go, cgo

Is it possible to mix in some C++ code in cgo?

I tried this:

```
package main
/* 
    #include <iostream>

    extern "C" void test(const char* str)
    {
        std::cout << str;
    }
*/
// #cgo CFLAGS: -x c++
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++
import "C"

func main() {
    C.test(C.CString("Testing!!!"))
}
```

But I get these errors:

```
error: 'char* CString(_GoString_)' cannot appear in a constant-exp
error: 'void test(const char*)' cannot appear in a constant-expres
error: invalid conversion from 'char* (*)(_GoString_)' to 'long long int' [-fpermissive]
error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(const char*)' to 'long long int' [-fpermissive]
```

I'm using go1.0.2 and MinGW-w64 4.7.1

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1476

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@ephemient provided a link to the feature request for this in the Go bug tracker. That in turn provided a link back to [How to use C++ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go/1721230) here on Stack Overflow.  There's a good discussion there, but the takeaways for me were:

1. The link to the Go FAQ ([Do Go programs link with C/C++ programs?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Do%5FGo%5Fprograms%5Flink%5Fwith%5FCpp%5Fprograms)):

   > ... The cgo program provides the mechanism for a “foreign function interface” to allow safe calling of C libraries from Go code. SWIG extends this capability to C++ libraries.
2. The link to [The SWIG documentation for Go](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Go.html).