# Golang : /usr/local/go/src/Make.: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, go

I'm trying to create a wrapper for some C++ code, following the example in [How to use C++ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go).  But when I run my Makefile I get:

```
Makefile:3: /usr/local/go/src/Make.: No such file or directory
Makefile:4: /usr/local/go/src/Make.pkg: No such file or directory
Makefile:6: *** missing separator.  Stop
```

Do I need to install an extra Go package or something to get Make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is deprecated and Makefiles are not used anymore. You can use SWIG to link with your C++ code. This is answered by the Go [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Do_Go_programs_link_with_Cpp_programs).

A more up to date tutorial on how to use SWIG can be found here:

http://zacg.github.io/blog/2013/06/06/calling-c-plus-plus-code-from-go-with-swig/