# How to wrap a library(with c++11 feature) in CGO

Tags: c++11, go, clang, cgo, openfst

1. My OS is Mac and the compiler is clang
2. I want to wrap a C++ library ([openfst](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/WebHome) , which uses C++11 feature ) in Go

   - I follow the method of Scott Wales in [How to use C++ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go) , and the demo given by him works well( and no need to write makefile)
   - First write a C wrapper for the C++ library.
   - Use cgo to import the C version header file
   - Write a test file and run `go test` to test.
3. I got errors caused by c++11 issues. It seems the fstlib.h contains some header files which use c++11 syntax.

```cpp
In file included from gofst.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/fst/fstlib.h:28:
In file included from /usr/local/include/fst/expanded-fst.h:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/fst/log.h:26:
/usr/local/include/fst/flags.h:143:50: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
/usr/local/include/fst/flags.h:174:37: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
```

4. I try to use `export CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"` to use C++11 but I got this.

```cpp
error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'
FAIL    _/Users/chaoyang/Learn/go/cgo/gofst [build failed]
```

Belows are all the files

gofst.h

```
//gofst.h

#ifndef GO_FST_H
#define GO_FST_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  typedef void* Fst;

  Fst FstInit(void);
  void FstFree(Fst f);
  void AddState(Fst f);
  void SetStart(Fst f, int startState);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

gofst.cpp

```cpp
//gofst.cpp
#include <fst/fstlib.h>
#include "gofst.h"

Fst FstInit()
{
  StdVectorFst fst = new StdVectorFst();
  return (void*)fst;
}
void FstFree(Fst f)
{
  StdVectorFst * fst = (StdVectorFst*)f;
  delete fst;
}

void AddState(Fst f)
{
  StdVectorFst * fst = (StdVectorFst*)f;
  f->AddState();
}

void SetStart(Fst f, int startState)
{
  StdVectorFst * fst = (StdVectorFst*)f;
  f->SetStart(startState);
}
```

gofst.go

```golang
// gofst.go
package gofst

// #include "gofst.h"
import "C"

//Fst structy
type Fst struct {
    fst C.Fst
}

//New create a new Fst object
func New() Fst {
    var ret Fst
    ret.fst = C.FstInit()
    return ret
}

//Free free the fst object
func (f Fst) Free() {
    C.FstFree(f.fst)
}

//AddState add a new state for fst
func (f Fst) AddState() {
    C.AddState(f.fst)
}

//SetStart set a new id for start state
func (f Fst) SetStart(state int) {
    C.SetStart(f.fst, state)
}
```

gofst_test.go

```golang
// gofst_test.go
package gofst

import "testing"

func TestFfst(t *testing.T) {
    fst := New()
    fst.AddState()
    fst.SetStart(0)
    foo.Free()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried SWIG? http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Go.html

Comment: Seems Add this into my go file solve the problem. // #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lfst

Comment: @JimB Thank you. I will try both.

Comment: Did any of these fix your issue, Chao Yang? I'm facing a similar error.