# Wrapping C++ function with arguments of non-primitive data types

Tags: c++, go, cgo

`Go` vs `C++` interoperability has been discussed many times so far ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go), for example), and generally it has been shown that it's possible to wrap `C++` functions in `C` functions, and than to wrap `C` functions in `CGO` functions. This is the way how to use `C++` code in `Go` application. However, the most of examples consider only functions with parameters of primitive data types (like `int` or `char *`).

But what if `C++` function expects STL containers like `std::vector` or `std::set` to be passed? There are no equivalents for them in `C`, so I have no idea what to pass from `C` to `C++`.

```
static Status GetApproximateMemoryUsageByType(
      const std::vector<DB*>& dbs,
      const std::unordered_set<const Cache*> cache_set,
      std::map<MemoryUtil::UsageType, uint64_t>* usage_by_type);
```

**UPD**

Just for the reference, here is the example of how this problem was [solved](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/commit/0bd2ede10e97944798449e0f954658fac8bfdbd2). This is a real function from `RocksDB C++ API`. In order to use it in `Go`, it should be wrapped in function (or several functions) that are written in `C++`, but look like as just they're written in plain `C`. These wrappers are compiled to library with `Go` binary links against.

Comment: Link in question doesn't work.

Comment: _"so I have no idea what to pass from C"_ probably some POD structure arrays.

Comment: Link in question DOES work for me.

Comment: Are these sophisticated objects _created_ by the C++ library, or is the client expected to construct them?

Comment: You either *convert* your data or *wrap* it (in practice you wrap a pointer to it) and provide access to it with C-style functions.