# Does Go support calling C++ function?

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I want to call some c++ functions(which are specific for my c++ library ) in Go. But I am not sure, does Go support that?

I've already tried that  [calling dll functions from go](https://yizhang82.dev/calling-c-from-go)

But it does not work for .so file

Do I have to write a c wrapper for my c++ code?

Comment: I've checked it, but i'm looking  for another way except C wrapper, if there is.

Comment: See the [recommendation for SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9931719/1256452) answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `.so` which is [Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) while your example uses `.dll` which is [Portable Executable Format (PE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). I'm not familiar with `GoLang` but it appears that [syscall](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) is used for lower level OS API, which is clear seeing that it uses `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, both part of `Windows API`. You would do roughly the same thing but using Linux API rather than Windows API.

Comment: I know, thats why I said "it does not work for .so file". I could not find anything about linux side except SWIG and writing wrapper

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought you were asking why the example you linked wasn't working for you, not that you specifically wanted to know how to load libraries from Linux.

Comment: No problem Pickle, even so thanks for your comment

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar at all with either Linux or GoLang, but from a cursory look it seems that you're looking for [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) to replace ``LoadLibrary`` and [dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to replace ``GetProcAddress``. From there you would invoke the imported method via ``syscall.Syscall(...)`` the same way as the example.