# Cgo pass a string to C file

Tags: go, cgo

I am using [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go/1721230#1721230) post about running c++ from go:

> I want to use [this function] in Go. I'll use the C interface
>
> ```
>   // foo.h
>   #ifdef __cplusplus
>   extern "C" {
>   #endif
>    typedef void* Foo;
>    Foo FooInit(void);
>    void FooFree(Foo);
>    void FooBar(Foo);
>   #ifdef __cplusplus
>   }
>   #endif
> ```

I did this, but **how can I pass a string as an argument to the C++ function?** I tried to pass a `rune[]` but it did not work.

Comment: I assume you mean a nul-terminated string as in C and not some C++ string class.  If so see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#go-strings-and-c-strings

Comment: I expanded your question with a quote from the reference you are citing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `Go` code:

```golang
// GetFileSizeC wrapper method for retrieve byte lenght of a file
func GetFileSizeC(filename string) int64 {
    // Cast a string to a 'C string'
    fname := C.CString(filename)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(fname))
    // get the file size of the file
    size := C.get_file_size(fname)
    return int64(size)
}
```

From C

```
long get_file_size(char *filename) {
  long fsize = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return fsize;
}
```

Remember that you need to add the headers library that you need before the import in the Go file:

```golang
package utils

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdio.h>   |
// #include <stdlib.h>  | -> these are the necessary system header
// #include <string.h>  |
// #include "cutils.h" <-- this is a custom header file
import "C"
import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
     ....
)
```

This is an old project that you can use for future working example:

https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoUtils

Comment: why do you call it as "cast" wherein it's literally a type conversation (which includes unnecessary (for this case) copy)?

Comment: Hi @Laevus, i can't understand your point. In order to call the C code is necessary to convert (you are right, is not a cast) the string and then free the data. Why is unnecessary the copy? Could you provide a simple test ?

Comment: ye, sorry, I forgot that string must be null terminated in that case. In the other one, i'd pass backing array pointer from the go's string