# CGO, pass a struct from go to c++

Tags: c++, c, go, struct, cgo

I am experimenting with cgo, and wanted to use c++ with cgo. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go) post about doing it. If I have a c++ struct named `Foo` and a go struct named `Foo`, I want to pass the go `Foo` to c++. I tried doing this:

```
//bind.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  #include "structs.hpp"
  void bindCgo(Foo bar);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

```
//structs.hpp

#ifndef STRUCTS_HPP_
#define STRUCTS_HPP_

typedef struct Foo {

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  std::string str;
  #endif

}
#endif
```

```
//bind.cc

#include "structs.hpp"
using namespace std;

void bindCgo(Foo bar) {
  cout << bar.str << endl; //this gives "sΘ\"
}
```

```
//main.go

import "unsafe"

// #cgo CFLAGS: -std=c99
// #include "bind.h"
import "C"

type Foo struct {
  str string
}

func main() {
  bar := Foo{""};

  C.bindCgo(((*C.Foo)(unsafe.Pointer(&bar))))
}
```

Now when I run this program, it gives me `sΘ\`. Is this normal, and how can I fix this?

I also have maps and vectors in my struct so using char* will not work

Comment: seems unlikely to ever work. `std::string` is a C++ class and Go doesn't play with C++, and the Go `str` type won't be understood by C. Should only pass primitive types