# Cgo undefined reference

Tags: go, cgo

Why the c function is not recognized in my .go file when using Cgo?
I followed all the process and tried the example on godoc, it worked but this one does not work, what is the reason?

**folder structure**

libsha.a

sha.cpp

sha.o

sha.h

main.go

**Code**

**sha.h**

```
#ifndef _SHA_H_
#define _SHA_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "TYPE.h"

typedef struct {
    U32 bits[2];
    U32 input[16];
    U32 state[5];
} SHA_CTX;

void SHA_Init(SHA_CTX *ctx);
void SHA_Update(SHA_CTX *ctx, U8 *in, int inbytes);
void SHA_Final(SHA_CTX *ctx, U8 *out);
void KS_SHA(U8 *out, U8 *in, int inbytes);

#endif
```

**sha.cpp**

```
  #include "sha.h"  
    void SHA_Init(SHA_CTX *ctx)
        {
            ctx->state[0] = INIT_H0;
            ctx->state[1] = INIT_H1;
            ctx->state[2] = INIT_H2;
            ctx->state[3] = INIT_H3;
            ctx->state[4] = INIT_H4;
            ctx->bits[0] = ctx->bits[1] = 0;
        }
```

**main.go**

```
package main


// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L . -lsha
// #include "sha.h"
import "C"
import "unsafe"

type CPoint struct {
    Point C.struct_SHA_CTX
}

func main() {
    point := CPoint{Point: C.struct_SHA_CTX{}}
    C.SHA_Init(point)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(point))

}
```

**Error**

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b001\_x002.o: in function `_cgo_6280fd3fea2a_Cfunc_SHA_Init':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:49: undefined reference to `SHA_Init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Why the SHA_Init function is not recognized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sha.cpp` file is not a `C` file, it's a `C++` file. By default, this means that when compiled, it won't have C linkage, meaning CGo will have no way to call it.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/2911436 for more information as to why it won't work by default.

#### Solutions

1. If `sha.cpp` can be easily converted to a pure `C` file, that would be the easiest. In the case of your code above, simply renaming it to `sha.c` seemed to work for me.
2. If that's not feasible, check out the post: [How to use C++ in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go/1721230)

#### Caveats:

I had to do a bit of refactoring in order to get this to work as I lacked a lot of the definitions used in your code samples.

- I couldn't try this with a `libsha.a`, and had to redefine all `U*` types as I didn't have the file (e.g. `U8` -> `uint8_t`).
- I had to delete functions aside from `SHA_Init` as their implementations weren't given.
- I renamed all of the `INIT_H*` ints in `sha.cpp` to be some constant in order to compile.
- I tested this on a Mac, and used `clang`, however running your code gave me a similar error so I believe the solution will be similar.

Comment: Thank you John, you are right I should try the link you shared for c++ and go, but I think it makes the compilation painful!!! I should try to convert it into C or reprogram the code in C calling the .h files