# how to integrate fairplay license sdk by using golang?

Tags: go, drm, fairplay

I have downloaded FairPlay Streaming Server SDK, but it is written by C++, and I use golang as programming language, how can I integrate it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [write a wrapper in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721230/6309), from which you can call your C++ SDK.
([example here](https://medium.com/@mehmetozcan/godan-c-fonksiyonu-%C3%A7a%C4%9F%C4%B1rmak-9c3a9875b065))

Then using [cgo](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo), you can compile, linking to your SDK library.
See a concrete example in "[Linking Dynamic C++ Libraries with Go](https://ataylor.io/blog/cgolinking/)" from [Brand Aaron Taylor](https://ataylor.io/about/)

> Specifying the location of this file requires custom flags for the compiler command.
> With a bit of searching I was able to find the `-L` flag, which, similarly to the `-I` flag, specifies a search directory for the compilation process as a whole.
>
> By specifying both Drafter’s build directory and dynamic library itself, we had a compiling C program!
>
> ```
> gcc ctest.o -L./drafter/build/out/Release/ -ldrafter -o ctest
> ```