# How do I make Golang CGO to use g++ linker for a c++ static library with extern "C" wrapper

Tags: c++, go

I am trying to make CGO link my C++ static library with GO code. I have written a C-wrapper header and c-source file with  extern "C" calls
like this

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and have added  `-stdc++` to the `LDFLAGS` in my .go file

```
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++14 -I.  -flto
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++ -L. -llibforgo
// #include "Wrapper.h"
import "C"
```

but the linker does not seem to find c++  standard calls ans is full of errors like

```
 undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
 undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
```

Here are related go environment variables

```
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
```

What I am doing wrong? How to tell cgo to use g++ instead of gcc? Maybe I should recompile
my static `c++` library with some additional options?

Comment: See [How to use C++ in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713214/1256452) (check for the more recent answers!).

Comment: Thank you, I have read this again, but I don't find the answer. It seems like there is an example for linking dynamic library, but not static.  Or if I am missing the answer to my case, could you point me please? Thank you again, Yuliana

Comment: I have found a strange solution, but it worked.  Put a dummy .cc file in the same directory.  https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/WXPBp6WTm-s

Comment: The linker is run only at the end of the compilation phase (by default anyway); the empty `.cc` file is making the Go build link against libstdc++ but you can put that in your link flags directly.

Comment: I did it - as I wrote in my initial post  and you can see in my example - but that did not help. So something is obviously wrong there with the cgo functioning.

Comment: I'm not sure what's in `libforgo` but probably `-lstdc++` must be listed last.