# How Call C++ Variables Using CGo For Standard Libraries

Tags: c++, go, mingw-w64, cgo

I am trying to get a variable value from a c++ code using cgo. For libraries ended in `.h`all  works fine, but for libraries like `<iostream>`, `<map>`, `<string>` etc, I got the following error:

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <iostream>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Below my code:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lc++
#include <iostream>
std::string plus() {
    return "Hello World!\n";
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    a := Plus_go()
    fmt.Println(a)

}
func Plus_go() string {
    return C.plus()
}
```

I added the `#cgo LDFLAGS: -lc++` flag because I saw this recommendation on an answer here on stackoverflow at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41615301/15024997.

I am using VS Code (not VS Studio), windows 10, Go 1.18 (lastest version).

I ran the following commands `go tool cgo -debug-gcc mycode.go` to trace compiler execution and output:

```
$ gcc -E -dM -xc -m64 - <<EOF

#line 1 "cgo-builtin-prolog"
#include <stddef.h> /* for ptrdiff_t and size_t below */

/* Define intgo when compiling with GCC.  */
typedef ptrdiff_t intgo;

#define GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef struct { const char *p; intgo n; } _GoString_;
typedef struct { char *p; intgo n; intgo c; } _GoBytes_;
_GoString_ GoString(char *p);
_GoString_ GoStringN(char *p, int l);
_GoBytes_ GoBytes(void *p, int n);
char *CString(_GoString_);
void *CBytes(_GoBytes_);
void *_CMalloc(size_t);

__attribute__ ((unused))
static size_t _GoStringLen(_GoString_ s) { return (size_t)s.n; }

__attribute__ ((unused))
static const char *_GoStringPtr(_GoString_ s) { return s.p; }
#line 3 "C:\\Users\\Home\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DevicesC++\\devices.go"


#include <iostream>
std::string plus() {
    return "Hello World!\n";
}

#line 1 "cgo-generated-wrapper"
EOF
C:\Users\Home\OneDrive\Desktop\DevicesC++\devices.go:5:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <iostream>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
C:\Users\Home\OneDrive\Desktop\DevicesC++\devices.go:5:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <iostream>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: _"Cgo lets Go packages call C code"_ - but the headers you try to include are C++ headers.

Comment: CGo also supports C++ according this page https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo, if I understood well

Comment: It mentions it at least so, perhaps... Can you see which compiler it uses? Try to make `Cgo` print out the full compilation command of the C or C++ compiler it uses.

Comment: I tried to show it on the output but I do not know how to do that, nevertheless I search the documentation and seems it use gcc according the page https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/cmd/cgo/gcc.go

Comment: Hmm, I don't know [tag:go] but I assume you do. Wouldn't it be possible to modify `gcc.go` to spit out the commands it's executing? That's the approach I'd take if it doesn't have options to do so built-in. What does the `cgo` option `-debug-gcc` do?

Comment: `gcc -E -dM -xc -m64` ... It's running the preprocessor only and `-xc` tells it to do it in C mode so the include paths for the C++ headers will be missing.

Comment: I insert this another flag `//#cgo CXXFLAGS: -x c++` in the code but I am getting the same results.

Comment: This statement is important: *When the Go tool sees that one or more Go files use the special import "C", it will look for other non-Go files in the directory and compile them as part of the Go package. Any .c, .s, .S or .sx files will be compiled with the C compiler. Any .cc, .cpp, or .cxx files will be compiled with the C++ compiler.* All C++ code must be in an appropriately named file; C++ code cannot appear in the Go comment.

Comment: @torek I have follow your suggestion (see on the post edited), but I also got the same error  `iostream: No such file or directory`

Comment: You cannot `#include` the CPP code from the Go comment. No C++ code can appear in the Go comment! You must use separate compilation of the C++ code. You may put C code in the Go comment that appears before `import "C"`, or if you don't need any C code as a shim between Cgo and C++, omit that comment entirely, but you can't put the C++ code into it in any way, and that covers `#include` as well.

Comment: But if I run the go code without any reference to the cpp I will not be able to get any info (in this case the string) from the .cpp.

Comment: That's not the actual problem you'll have here. Instead, you have a whole slew of *different* problems once you fix the cpp file issue. I'll see about writing up a real answer here.

Comment: The  `-debug-gcc` output shows that the `gcc` is being used.  It does not implicitly set the default  C++ library header path or link the C++ library - for that it would have to use `g++` or set the paths and link the library explicitly.  Moreover the `-xc` option forces C compilation explicitly.

Comment: Clearly this is an X-Y problem.  You need interoperability between go and c++, you have made an erroneous attempt at that and are then asking a question about your flawed solution.  Ask about interoperability.  If all you need is to access a variable in the C++ code, what does <iostream> have to do with that?  Why would you include iostream in any case - none of the code uses it - <string> would make more sense - though that won't work either.  Also you cannot "call" a variable - and your code has nothing to do with C++ variables in any event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGo allows you to link your Go code against code that implements the C-style foreign function interfaces.  This *does not mean* that you can just stick arbitrary-language code into place.

Let's start with the first problem, which is that the `import "C"` line in one of your Go files must contain *only C code* above it.  That is:

```
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
extern char *cstyle_plus();
*/
```

is OK, but:

```
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
extern std::string *plus();
*/
```

is not, nor may you `#include` any C++ header here.  To oversimplify things a bit, the comment here is in effect snipped out and fed to *a C compiler*.  If it's not valid C, it won't compile.

If you want to include C++ code, you can, but you must put it in a separate file or files (technically speaking, a "translation unit" in C or C++ terminology).  CGo will then compile that file to object code.

The next problem, however, is that the object code *must* conform to the C [Foreign Function Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) implemented by CGo.  This means your C++ code must *return C types* (and/or receive such types as arguments).  As `std::string` is not a C string, you literally can't return it directly.

It's not very efficient (and there exist some attempts to work around this), but the usual method for dealing with this is to have C functions return C-style "char *" or "const char *" strings.  If the string itself has non-static duration—as yours does—you must use `malloc` here, specifically the *C* `malloc` (`std::malloc` may be a non-interoperable one).

The function itself must also be callable *from* C code.  This means we'll need to use `extern "C"` around it.

Hence, our `plus.cpp` file (or whatever you would like to call it) might read this way:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

std::string plus() {
        return "Hello World!\n";
}

extern "C" {
char *cstyle_plus() {
        // Ideally we'd use strdup here, but Windows calls it _strdup
        char *ret = static_cast<char *>(malloc(plus().length() + 1));
        if (ret != NULL) {
                strcpy(ret, plus().c_str());
        }
        return static_cast<char *>(ret);
}
}
```

We can then invoke this from Go using this `main.go`:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
extern char *cstyle_plus();
*/
import "C"
import (
        "fmt"
        "unsafe"
)

func Plus_go() string {
        s := C.cstyle_plus()
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
        return C.GoString(s)
}

func main() {
        a := Plus_go()
        fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Adding a trivial `go.mod` and building, the resulting code runs; the double newline is because the C string has a newline in it, and `fmt.Println` adds a newline:

```
$ go build
$ ./cgo_cpp
Hello World!
```

This code is a bit sloppy: should `malloc` fail, it returns NULL, and `C.GoString` turns that into an empty string.  However, real code should try, as much as possible, to avoid this kind of silly allocation-and-free sequence: we might know the string length, or have a `static` string that does not require this kind of silly `malloc`, for instance.

Comment: In my machine I needed to add `#include <cstring>` in plus.cpp to work as shown. Thank you so much for the explanation and codes.